# Get the value from another cell if a pattern matches a string in another cell of the same row

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image: Sample template]

Hi,

I have an Excel Workbook with above data. I use Pandas to read through the Excel sheet in my Python script.

My requirement is if I find YES in the Primary Key column, I need to get the Data Element value of that row.

So from the above sample, I need to get the 3 Data Element's value into an array variable.

I tried with the below piece of code and couldn't achieve it.

```
PK_COLUMNS={}

workbook_sheet = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name,sheet_name=i,keep_default_na=False)
workbook_sheet=workbook_sheet.fillna("NULL", inplace = False)
df=pd.DataFrame(workbook_sheet,columns=[0])
total_rows=len(df.axes[0]) 
h=0
while h<total_rows:
    CURRENT_COLUMN=workbook_sheet["Primary Key"].fillna("NULL", inplace = False)
    #print(CURRENT_COLUMN)
    for i in CURRENT_COLUMN:
        if str(i).upper() == 'YES':
            PK_COLUMNS[h]=workbook_sheet.iat[h,0].strip()
            print(PK_COLUMNS)
            h=h+1
        else:
            print ("NULL")
    print(PK_COLUMNS)
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Python 3.7 with Pandas.

Comment: `workbook_sheet.loc[workbook_sheet['Primary Key']=='YES', 'Data Element'].to_list()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang That works awesome. Thanks.
Any idea on how do I get the values of 'Data Element' 'Type & Size' and 'Nullable' columns where 'Primary Key' Columns is YES.

Comment: `workbook_sheet.loc[workbook_sheet['Primary Key']=='YES', [ 'Data Element', 'Nullable',...] ].to_list()`?